# jQuery not centering in IE browsers using both jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What other alternative can you guys suggest?

Below is the structure for the dialog:

```
<div id="dialogbox" title="message box">
  <p>sample content</P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be sure without seeing the context, but it sounds like you are triggering the [Qurks rendering mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). This has many undesirable features, including highly broken CSS support.

Add a Doctype that triggers Standards rendering mode, such as the HTML 5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```